# Navigation Drawer Header is not hiding

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I tried to create one simple app with Drawer Menu. I created a project with Android Studio and select Navigation Drawer Layout. I'm trying to hide navigation drawer header and put it on toolbar... I found the way to put on toolbar but I can't find hide RED part of header in picture. Can you help me please.

[image: navigation drawer header]

Here is my layout page xml codes

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" //With this code i put menu under toolbar
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new FirstFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new SecondFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new ThirdFragment()).commit();
    }   else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

How can I hide that red part??

Answer (score 3):

Set `fitsystemwindow=false` under *android.support.design.widget.NavigationView* in xml.

Answer (score 2):

Use this In your `MainActivity` if you want to do it programmatically else see the second option below.

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
         header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**OR** if you not wanna use that and want to accomplish this via xml then check below option.
In your xml file of main activity you should have `NavigationView` like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view_I"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header">
```

Remove last line from the above `NavigationView` which is this

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
```

Comment: Yes i understand this solution i also delete that line app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header" but when i run program that gray part in picture is always stay there???

Answer (score 0):

Add below code inside of `onCreateView()` of NavigationDrawer Fragment class

```
View headerView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
 navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
 navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Note:- relace R.layout.drawer_header by your header view resource file.

Comment: hi @madhan i dont have navigationdrawer fragment class. I just have MainActivity and i'm using there 'onCreate()' function.. where is coming 'nvigationview' ??

Comment: Ok, use that code where you handle the navigationdrawer layout.

Comment: I put on MainActivity under onCreate method but its not worked :(

Comment: In `R.layout.nav_header_navigation` resource set `android:visibility="gone" ` . Note : but it's not a best practice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117887/discussion-between-saulyasar-and-madhan-kumar).